# Настройка групповой политики Google Chrome

Tags: windows, google-chrome, group-policy

Здравствуйте!
У меня возник такой вопрос, с которым я так и не смог разобраться, даже вчитываясь в документацию (допуская, что что-то не смог понять на английском языке).
[chromium.org/administrators/url-blacklist-filter-format](http://chromium.org/administrators/url-blacklist-filter-format) - документация

Я решил поставить на несколько машин групповые политики Chrome.
И нужно было прописать несколько сайтов, к которым доступ должен быть закрыт.

Прочитав документацию, я вписал нужные сайты, однако не понял один момент.
К примеру, мне нужно заблокировать сайт, который имеет такой вид:

sub.example.* - где "*" это всевозможные варианты доменов первого уровня.

Я пробовал писать sub.example.*, sub.example. и многое другое, что даже уже не имело смысла, но так и не смог заблокировать таким образом доступ к сайту, а писать отдельно каждые домены первого уровня не хочется.

Возможно ли вообще заблокировать sub.example.*, где звездочка все домены первого уровня?